# Why float left doesn't work

Tags: html, css, layout, fluid

I'm building a website with fluid layout and I want avoid things like setting dimensions. I'm having success in almost everything, but I have a div that doesn't work as expected. See this link: http://cssdesk.com/Bshqe.
I expect that "div_botao_comecar_convite_cadastro_b" were placed to the right of "div_descricao_curta_convite_cadastro_b", but it was placed below this div. I want that the div be placed at left.
As I say, I don't want set a width for anyone div. Sorry for bad english. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You said that you don't want to set a specific width for any element, but if you want everything on a line, you should really set #div_elementos_convite_cadastro_b 's width

Comment: Why? If the element is set with "float: left;", it should not be left from the previous element? Why is it below? I don't understand this behaviour.

Comment: @user3753202 you said you don't want to set any width. so when the left divs contents expans, right div don't have any space left to say in the same row. what else do you expect..? :/

Comment: Why this doesn't happen with #div_descricao_curta_convite_cadastro_b?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to set a specific `width` but want the children elements aligned horizontally, use css3 [flexboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) -

apply `display:flex` to `#div_elementos_convite_cadastro_b` and adjust the other css accordingly....

[demo](http://cssdesk.com/7h2TX)

more about flexboxes @ [CSSTricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Flexboxes are awesomes. The problem is IE support.

Comment: well it's supported in ie 10 and 11. btw you can't get all the good that easily... this is web..

Comment: I can only to wait a few more years until it is irrelevant support IE ​​9.